# Paypal "Subscribe" button: Is it possible to let the subscriber set the amount?

Tags: paypal

I'm setting up a recurring payment option on my website. I'd like to have two options:

- Option 1 (for individuals): Fixed $6/mo subscription
- Option 2 (for organizations): A subscription where the amount is set by the subscriber

So, I would like to enable the subscriber of Option 2 to set the amount of the monthly subscription themselves.

PayPal's "Subscribe" button does not seem to allow that:

[image]

When I leave the "Amount" field of the 2nd option empty, I get an error:

[image]

So, is this not possible? Do all options require fixed amounts?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal should generate an HTML snippet of the button to place on your site. I would create a developer account to test this. You can take the code with the amount field filled in from PayPal then place it on your site and leave it blank. Set an input hidden and when Groups is selected display the input on the page and text explaining to the visitor to enter an amount. Using the paypal sandbox you can submit this and see if it works.